# Oracle - DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE failed with no error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm using for first time the DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE pkg.
I've try a simple operation: I've two table t1 and t2 and I'm tring to insert all the records of t2 into t1.

```
begin
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task('myTsk1');
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chuncks_by_rowid(task_name => 'myTsk1',
    table_owner => 'mySchema',
    table_name => 't2',
    bt_row => TRUE,
    chunk_size => 1000
  );
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(task_name => 'myTsk1',
    sql_stmt => 'insert /*+ parallel */ into mySchema.t1 (select * from mySchema.t2 where rowid between :start_id and :end_id)',
    language_flag => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
    parallel_leveò => 4
  );
end;
```

After the `create_task` and `create_chuncks_by_rowid` I see the job un chunked status in `user_parallel_execute_task` and in `user_parallel_execute_chunks` I see the chunks created.

When executed the run_task after few second the execution was completed.
If I check in `user_parallel_execute_task` table all are set as UNASSIGNED.

So I checked the `user_scheduler_job_run_details` and `all_scheduler_job_run_details` for know the cause of the error but ERROR# column is 0 and ADDITIONAL_INFO is null. Added the exception trap but no exception was raised too.

Comment: I don't think you would be wanting to have the PARALLEL hint because the parallel part if being done by DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.  You want each of the slaves to run in serial, because otherwise, the first one to execute would lock the entire table anyway

Comment: Oh ok, so the first one go on TM and the second will wait untill the first end, right?
If yes, is enough remove the parallel hint?

Comment: Definitely *try* it without the hint to see if that is the cause

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald thanks for the help! By removing the hint all works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested @ConnorMcDonald by removing the parallel hint the task run correctly!

```
begin
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task('myTsk1');
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chuncks_by_rowid(task_name => 'myTsk1',
    table_owner => 'mySchema',
    table_name => 't2',
    bt_row => TRUE,
    chunk_size => 1000
  );
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(task_name => 'myTsk1',
    sql_stmt => 'insert into mySchema.t1 (select * from mySchema.t2 where rowid between :start_id and :end_id)',
    language_flag => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
    parallel_leveò => 4
  );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case, the cause was a syntax error in the passed SQL statement. It seems that Oracle doesn't throw an error with a clearer message but just fails silently, which is a shame.